# Checking if a shared memory exists and if it does access it

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have another program1 where i create a shared memory and i have a program2 that i want to check if the shared memory has been created, if not then print an error and dont do nothing and if it has been created already then acess it.
If the shared memory has been created before then it works fine and i can acess it but the problem im having is that if the shared memory has not been created then instead of doing nothing and printing an error the program2 creates the shared memory and i didn't want that to happen.
Any help would be appreciated and please ask any information that might be usefull, thanks!

```
void main(){

int sm_id;
sm_id = shmget(9000, MAX_USERS * sizeof(User), IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
if(sm_id>0){
    perror("Shared memory has not been created yet");
    exit(1);
}else{
    sm_id = shmget(9000, MAX_USERS * sizeof(User), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    list = (User *)shmat(sm_id,0,0);
    exit_on_null(list, "Exit on null(error attach)");
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe simply to call `shmget` without `IPC_CREAT` flag?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use System V shared memory?  POSIX shared memory is much easier to work with.  Check `shm_open`.

Comment: It worked, im using shmget because its for a project and since the professors use that... thanks for the tip anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `IPC_CREAT` flag. It will return error `ENOENT` if that shared memory does not exist.

Check the man page for further information..

[SHMGET](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html)

Comment: It worked, i assumed we always had to use IPC_CREAT in order for it to work since i hadn't seen an example without it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Livernal :-)... Check the man page as well, you will have more information from there.